# How to fix line breaks in the text cdr file?

Tags: awk, sed, cat, cdr

i have following output from cdr file as shown in the below code snippet.

```
2021-10-27 00:06:53,203:16344:5:0:4:573192000019::6:0:4:573160001511:*999#:1:1:573160032001:1:6:732123904909775:1:1:573156068892:::::SUCCESS:PULL:2021-10-2700:06:53.203:101630:20076482:28389:2
,2:aa8c2b31-ac49-4c16-9e2f-f8a83ba63cd6
2021-10-27 00:06:57,120:16344:5:0:4:573192000019::6:0:4:573160001511:*111#:1:1:573160032002:1:6:732123907508180:1:1:573134396303:::::SUCCESS:PULL:2021-10-27 00:06:57.12:101631:26706476:11566:3,3,3192244169:d21e7dca-6dfa-43e6-8bcd-b95ebd35cdea
```

As can be seen in the Code Snippet, line number 2 should be part of line number 1, but there is a line break splitting the transaction into two lines. The requirement is following.

```
2021-10-27 00:06:53,203:16344:5:0:4:573192000019::6:0:4:573160001511:*999#:1:1:573160032001:1:6:732123904909775:1:1:573156068892:::::SUCCESS:PULL:2021-10-2700:06:53.203:101630:20076482:28389:2,2:aa8c2b31-ac49-4c16-9e2f-f8a83ba63cd6
2021-10-27 00:06:57,120:16344:5:0:4:573192000019::6:0:4:573160001511:*111#:1:1:573160032002:1:6:732123907508180:1:1:573134396303:::::SUCCESS:PULL:2021-10-27 00:06:57.12:101631:26706476:11566:3,3,3192244169:d21e7dca-6dfa-43e6-8bcd-b95ebd35cdea
```

How can this be done in already generated file  ? There are thousands of similar lines in the cdr file which needs to corrected .TIA

Comment: How can you tell when a line is complete?

Comment: Hello @beta Each new line starts with a datetime parameter. I just edited my question to give  more context of the situation .TIA

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (/^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}/ ? ors : ""), $0; ors=ORS} END{print ""}' file
2021-10-27 00:06:53,203:16344:5:0:4:573192000019::6:0:4:573160001511:*999#:1:1:573160032001:1:6:732123904909775:1:1:573156068892:::::SUCCESS:PULL:2021-10-2700:06:53.203:101630:20076482:28389:2,2:aa8c2b31-ac49-4c16-9e2f-f8a83ba63cd6
2021-10-27 00:06:57,120:16344:5:0:4:573192000019::6:0:4:573160001511:*111#:1:1:573160032002:1:6:732123907508180:1:1:573134396303:::::SUCCESS:PULL:2021-10-27 00:06:57.12:101631:26706476:11566:3,3,3192244169:d21e7dca-6dfa-43e6-8bcd-b95ebd35cdea
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F ':' 'NF!=37 { curr=$0; getline; $0 = curr $0 }1' file
```

Output:

```
2021-10-27 00:06:53,203:16344:5:0:4:573192000019::6:0:4:573160001511:*999#:1:1:573160032001:1:6:732123904909775:1:1:573156068892:::::SUCCESS:PULL:2021-10-2700:06:53.203:101630:20076482:28389:2,2:aa8c2b31-ac49-4c16-9e2f-f8a83ba63cd6
2021-10-27 00:06:57,120:16344:5:0:4:573192000019::6:0:4:573160001511:*111#:1:1:573160032002:1:6:732123907508180:1:1:573134396303:::::SUCCESS:PULL:2021-10-27 00:06:57.12:101631:26706476:11566:3,3,3192244169:d21e7dca-6dfa-43e6-8bcd-b95ebd35cdea
```

I assume that each row should have 37 columns.

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;/\n....-..-.. ..:..:..,/!s/\n//;ta;P;D' file
```

Open a 2 line window in the pattern space.

If the second line does not begin with a date and time, remove the newline (append line 2 to line 1), append the next line and repeat until failure.

Print/delete the first of the two lines and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk '
/^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}/ {       # if the record starts with a date
    if (line) print line                                # flush the line buffer
    line = ""
}
{
    line = line $0                                      # append the current record to the line buffer
}
END {
    if (line) print line                                # flush the line buffer at the end of the file
}
' file.txt
```

Output with the provided example:

```
2021-10-27 00:06:53,203:16344:5:0:4:573192000019::6:0:4:573160001511:*999#:1:1:573160032001:1:6:732123904909775:1:1:573156068892:::::SUCCESS:PULL:2021-10-2700:06:53.203:101630:20076482:28389:2,2:aa8c2b31-ac49-4c16-9e2f-f8a83ba63cd6
2021-10-27 00:06:57,120:16344:5:0:4:573192000019::6:0:4:573160001511:*111#:1:1:573160032002:1:6:732123907508180:1:1:573134396303:::::SUCCESS:PULL:2021-10-27 00:06:57.12:101631:26706476:11566:3,3,3192244169:d21e7dca-6dfa-43e6-8bcd-b95ebd35cdea
```